# The function is running on model 3 times

Tags: angular

I created a class as a model file

```
export class Category {
    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public numberOfVisits: number
    ) {
    }

    addVisit(){
        return this.numberOfVisits += 1;
    }
}
```

This is my component

```
export class AppComponent {
  category: Category;
  constructor() {
    this.category = new Category('Search', 1);
  }
}
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<div class="block">
 {{category.name}}<br />
 Number of visits: {{category.addVisit()}}
</div>
```

When I am refreshing the page I get: Number of visits: 3
However, I expect to get 1.
When I am debugging, I see that the program is running on the model 3 times.
Does anyone have any idea, why?

Comment: You're most likely seeing AngularJS's digest cycle in action. Your `addVisit()` call is inside an interpolation in your HTML, and digests cause interpolations to potentially trigger several times until models are assumed to be stable. If you want to leave the interpolation in place, a solution would be to debounce the increment.

Comment: Debounce just creating a delay effect, isn't it?

Comment: Using a debounce prevents multiple calls to the same function in a short period of time from executing the full body of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate getter for getting visits count.
Update your model as shown below:

```
export class Category {
    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public numberOfVisits: number
    ) {
    }
    addVisit(){
        return this.numberOfVisits += 1;
    }
    getVisits(){
      return this.numberOfVisits;
    }
}
```

And your sample template:

```
<div class="block">
  <button (click)="category.addVisit()">addVisit +1</button>
  <br> {{category.name}}
  <br /> Number of visits: {{category.getVisits()}}
</div>
```

And please check the working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7YFJYyQleaGDgfP0oPwD?p=preview)